# How to use an external API with Java in RESTful Springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I'm currently working on a Java RESTful Springboot project and trying to use an external API in order to submit data. The external API uses HTTP PUT() methods and two parameters parsing in the body. I was following few tutorials online but didn't work on any of them yet.

If anyone has a better suggestion please help me.

TIA.

Comment: you can use RestTemplate to make HTTP calls to external API's